# Is it possible to upload audio file to server using put request (Not multipart request) in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, iphone, alamofire, multipartform-data, nsurlsession

I need to upload audio file recorded in iOS device to server using `PUT` method in request. Now, I am confused that is it possible to upload audio file to server without multipart request in iOS Swift.

Comment: You can't upload audio file without multipart, you have to use multipart for upload audio file to server

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2 ? Put should "update", not create ressources (https://reqbin.com/Article/HttpPut) which would be "POST".

Comment: i did try different technique but didn't work. Actually i am uploading audio on signed url (which is created on our server ). On android and web side thay are uploading audio file by normal put request with audio file in body. and even i am trying to upload it from postman but still its not working@SilverskyTechnology

the server reponse with status code of 403 with message signature mismatch

Comment: Response : i did try different methods (put, post and multipart) but still i am getting below response from server

response >>> success("<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>

Comment: "SignatureDoesNotMatch" indicates that you're doing something incorrect with the rest of the API, unrelated to putting the data (PUT does not require a signature). You are probably missing a required header, but it's possible your API requires some other format than raw data. To help you, we'd need access to your server's API documentation. It's unclear what you're doing on the Android side.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert to base64 string and repeat call put if server can accept base64 request , if server can’t accept that you can’t. see documentation or contact server developer to find a way both can compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Create an URLRequest with a PUT method:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "PUT"
```

And then upload your data:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: data)
task.resume()
```

There's no need for a multipart if the server doesn't want hat.

Comment: i did try this approach but got 403 response

Comment: Your question is about how to PUT data, but your real problem is that you actual problem is around misusing this server API. We don't know what the server is, so probably can't help you without that without details of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolved the issue using this this approach. Left the Content-Type empty

[Alamofire image upload with PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000281/alamofire-image-upload-with-put)